# How to make so, that exceptions don't thrown in Enum.valuesOf()?

Tags: java, jpa, enums, specifications

I have class `BookSpecBuider` that create **JPA Specification** from dto.

**BookSpecBuider** class:

```
public class BookSpecBuilder {
    public Specification<Book> getSpec(BookSearchDto bookSearchDto) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (bookSearchDto.getGenre() != null) {
                predicates.add(root.get("genre").in(bookSearchDto.getGenre()));
            }
// another conditions
```

**Genre**
is enum-class, so I had problem that in my **BookSearchDto** Genre is String and it had problem with mapping.

I change it in my **if-block**:

```
predicates.add(root.get("genre").in(Genre.valueOf(bookSearchDto.getGenre())));
```

But now I have problem with exceptions, if I get String of Genre, that my enum doesn't have.
What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Ummm... by catching and handling the exception?

Comment: I think that it is not very beautiful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest create another enum entry called `Unknown` (or any name) and create a new static method call `.of()` (or any name that you preferred) inside your Genre enum,

```java
enum Genre {    
    public static Genre of(String genre) {
        for(Genre g : values()) {
            if (g.name().equalsIgnoreCase(genre)) {
                return g;
            }
        }
        return Unknown;
    }
}
```

Then this will avoid unnecessary exception.

Comment: The caveat is that that `Unknown` suddenly becomes a valid value for the `genre` property. Business logic needs to be adjusted to expect this extra option for `Genre` (e.g. when the `Book` is created extra validation might be needed to exclude `Unknown` as a valid value etc.)

Comment: @crizzis I validate it in BookSpecBuilder in if-block. I agree with you, but I don't know best way to avoid all this problems.